# Fault Exception Usage

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap, backend

I recently found myself confused about Fault Exceptions.

I have this simple wcf service. It exposes 3 operations 'Validate', 'Post', and 'Cancel'. On each operation I have different kinds of **error messages** requirements.

Lets say for validation operation I have to communicate to the client which fields are not valid. But for posting and cancellation its just a 'Failed posting/cancellation' response.

So, my question is: What could be a better option for failed operation responses? Create a custom fault exception that could hold all this error data? or, don't throw an exception and instead return the errors within the response message and let the client decide whether it has errors or not?

In advance, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FaultExceptions can wrap your own custom details object.

[FaulException TDetail Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576199.aspx)

I would pass back that it failed with the details of why.